# Create a series expansion with a custom function as basis

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, fourier-series

just as we can expand any given function $f(x)$ as a sum of sine and cosine functions, i. e., Fourier series

$f(x)=a_0+\sum a_k\cos(kx\omega)+\sum b_k\sin(kx\omega)$

or as power series, i. e., Taylor series

$f(x)=\sum c_k x^k$

Is there a way to systematically construct a series using a random function as the basis? Let us say use $\tan(x)$ as the basis  and then have something like

$f(x)=\sum h_k\tan(kx\omega)$ or perhaps  $f(x)=\sum p_k\tan(x)^k$.

In particular, I am interested in expand the identity function $f(x)=x$ as a sum of $\tanh(x)$ terms.
So far I have tried to construct this backwards from the Taylor series of $\tanh(x)$

Since

$\tanh(x)=x−x^3/3+2x^5/15−17x^7/315+⋯=\sum 2^{2n}(2^{2n}−1)B_{2n}(2n−1)/(2n)!$  with $B_n$ the Bernoulli numbers

I can construct the following terms

$\frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n}−1)B_{2n}(2n−1)\tanh(x)^{2n-1}}{2n!}|_{n=2}=x^3/3+⋯$

$\frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n}−1)B_{2n}(2n−1)\tanh(x)^{2n-1}}{2n!}|_{n=3}=-2x^5/15+⋯$

then by summing the left-hand-side expression with $\tanh(x)$ I get a function that is closer to the identity for longer than just $\tanh(x)$ jet I am not sure how robust my idea is.
[image]
Any ideas here?

Comment: For starters, the claim that *"... we can expand any given function $f(x)$ as a sum of sine and cosine functions, ... or as power series, ..."* is simply not true -- not any, far from that.

Comment: One way to approach this is to construct a differential equation with your set of custom functions $f_n$ as the eigenfunctions. If this DE may be cast in regular [Sturm–Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) form over some interval, the eigenfunctions are complete (within said interval) and may be used as a basis to expand other functions